# Adding button on android canvasa

Tags: android

How to add a button on the canvas in android from the activity class. I am not using any layout xml here. Any sort of code will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will make a container (a layout object) where you will add your button. A button is a `View` object so it cannot be added to a `canvas`.

On the `canvas` you can only draw static images and graphics and you won't interact with them by default like you do with a button.

I also recommend you to define the layout in the XML. It is a really good practice and helps you separate the layers of your application (presentation, controller, engine)

Comment: I am doing this - 

  layout = new FrameLayout(this);
  
  
  DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(this);
  // drawingPanel.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  button_clear = new Button(this);
  button_clear.setText("Clear Screen");
  button_clear.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);
  layout.addView(button_clear);

  layout.addView(drawingPanel);

  setContentView(layout);

But I am not able to see my button. It is still just showing the canvas?

Comment: I want to see the button , but is does not appear? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you comment `layout.addView(drawingPanel);` do you get your button on the screen?

Comment: it does but its covering the whole screen.strange!

Comment: I forgot to add 
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
after this they appear only if i comment the drawingpanel. but as soon as i add the drawingpanel they do not show up.

Comment: I believe that the `drawingpanel` covers the button that is trapped underneath. So try this one too: add the button last

Comment: :) Cool. Good luck with your app